# Code keeps skipping input for one line in only one case

Tags: java, input

Iv'e been writing code for a TicTacToe game and I've gotten stuck on one of my loops, where the case where the player enters input for a spot that's already been marked, it then prompts the user for input again. Problem being that it's only case where the code skips a line for input. What Should I do?

```
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   boolean bool = false;

   System.out.println("It is the player's move");
   System.out.println("Give me your best move!");

   while(!bool){
           String Answer = input.nextLine();

           Answer = validateUserResponse(Answer);

           int move = Integer.parseInt(Answer);

           if(validatePlayerMove(move))
           {
               if(checkPositionAvailability(move))
               {
                   board[move] = 'H'; //make 'H' for player move
                   bool = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("Position not available.\nMake a different choice.");
                   Answer = input.nextLine();
               }
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("Invalid entry!");
               Answer = input.nextLine();
           }
       }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say, "the code skips a line for input"?

Answer (score 1):

So I've figured it out, I was prompting two inputs for in my bool loop, so I simply had to move the first input outside the loop.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean bool = false;

       System.out.println("It is the player's move");
       System.out.println("Give me your best move!");

       String Answer = input.nextLine();

       while(!bool){

           Answer = validateUserResponse(Answer);

           int move = Integer.parseInt(Answer);

           if(validatePlayerMove(move))
           {
               if(checkPositionAvailability(move))
               {
                   board[move] = 'H'; //make 'H' for player move
                   bool = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("Position not available.\nMake a different choice.");
                   Answer = input.nextLine();
               }
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("Invalid entry!");
               Answer = input.nextLine();
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In either of the cases:

```
System.out.println("Position not available.\nMake a different choice.");
Answer = input.nextLine();
```

and

```
System.out.println("Invalid entry!");
Answer = input.nextLine();
```

... the `Answer` is obtained twice. Once after the message, then again in the first line of the loop body, hence the program apparently skips an answer in each case.